# if statement keeps looping after else?

Tags: python

I am still learning the fundamentals of Python, but I am getting stuck on this custom calculator program I am attempting to finish.

```
while True:

    print('Welcome. Below, type the number associated to begin calculating:')
    print('1: Addition')
    print('2: Subtraction')
    print('3: Multiplication')
    print('4: Division')

    pick = int(input('Enter the number associated with your calculation: '))
    if pick != (1, 5):
        print('Please enter an option given.')
    else:
        continue

def addNumber():
    if pick == 1:
        print('-------------------------')
        print('You have chosen #1 - Addition.')
        num1 = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
        num2 = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
        print('Your sum is equal to:', num1 + num2)
        print('-------------------------')

addNumber()
```

The first function is addition, and the rest of the functions are its own for each choice. This next part is the bottom, allowing the user to restart if chosen.

```
again = str(input('Would you like to calculate again?\n'))
if again == 'Yes':
    continue
else:
    break
```

There is no issue if the user tries to put a value outside of the range of 1-4 (prompting to try again), but if someone picks a shown option (like they're supposed to), `'Please enter an option given.'` shows up.

```
Welcome. Below, type the number associated to begin calculating:
1: Addition
2: Subtraction
3: Multiplication
4: Division
Enter the number associated with your calculation: 1
Please enter an option given.
You have chosen #1 - Addition.
Enter your first number:
```

How should I rewrite that if/else parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: @Makoto the testing of values is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your if-block could look like this:

```
if pick not in range(1, 5):
    print('Please enter an option given.')
    continue
else:
    functions[pick]()
```

And you could define a `functions` dictonary on the top like this:

```
functions = {1: addNumber, 2: subNumber, 3: multiplyNumber, 4: divideNumber}
```

And make rest of the functions like you've already made the `addNumber()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem in this line `if pick in range(1, 5):`

Here is my suggestion:

```
def addNumber():
    if pick == 1:
        print('-------------------------')
        print('You have chosen #1 - Addition.')
        num1 = int(input('Enter your first number: '))
        num2 = int(input('Enter your second number: '))
        print('Your sum is equal to:', num1 + num2)
        print('-------------------------')



while True:
    print('Welcome. Below, type the number associated to begin calculating:')
    print('1: Addition')
    print('2: Subtraction')
    print('3: Multiplication')
    print('4: Division')

    pick = int(input('Enter the number associated with your calculation: '))
    if pick in range(1, 5):
        if pick==1:
            addNumber()
        elif pick==2:
            subsNumber() # just as an example, but you can replace it 
        elif pick==3:
            MultipNumber() # same 
        else:
            divideNumber() # same
    else:
        print('Please enter an option given.')
```

Comment: Is this more of a personal preference, or would you consider it more clean, good code?

Comment: There is no just one way to do it. This was my suggestion that I think it's better and cleaner. You can take and change as you want ! maybe you can use `pick not in range(1, 5)` and adjust it accordingly.